# Intelij Idea Error : Unable to continue until an android sdk is specified

Tags: intellij-idea

After updgrading to Intellij Idea 2021.1, I am not able to open existing gradle java projects.
The project opens and then a modal dialog is displayed asking me for the path to an Android SDK.
As I do not do any Android development I do not have an Android SDK installed.
When I press cancel on the dialog the IDE exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround:
Go to Settings -> Plugins and disable the Android plugin in